# Is there a way to find out the type of video on youtube using youtube api for android

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I would like to find out the type of the video using android youtube api. Example, i would like to know if the video on the youtube is a music video or a movie trailer or something else?
Is there a way to find it out?

Comment: You could look at the tags/categorization of the videos, maybe?

Comment: Does YouTube API provide tags and categorization? Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the API tool [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) I was able to grab some videos under a certain category (Music | ID: `10`).

As long as you request all fields for the videos, it should return any tags/keywords with each video as well if you needed to do some further filtering on your end.

For example this request: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&hl=EN&maxResults=50&regionCode=US&videoCategoryId=10&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Returns 50 mostPopular videos in the Music category.

---

To find category IDs, you can use [this API tool](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list#try-it) to get started

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the video title and then try to 'guess' from that...  but that is about it. Youtube doesn't give other meta-data than that.

need to use https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list to find the ids of the videos you want then use 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list to get the data from the video(s)